# Different Child level Headers in Primeng Treetable

Tags: angular, angular7, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-treetable

How can I implement a primeng tree table with different child level header?
I am using angular 7 and primeng V7
Data is like below:

```
 {
      "label":"Parent 1",
      "data":{
          "name":"Parent 1"
      },
      "children": this.resultData1
  },
  {
    "label":"Parent 2",
    "data":{
        "name":"Parent 2"
    },
    "children": this.resultData2
}
```

And child elements are

```
resultData1 : Array<any> = [
    {data:{"status":"OK","AppId":"dsil1","GenId":"123"}},
    {data:{"status":"OK","AppId":"dsil2","GenId":"124"}},
    {data:{"status":"OK","AppId":"dsil3","GenId":"125"}},
    {data:{"status":"OK","AppId":"dsil4","GenId":"126"}}
    ]
 resultData2 : Array<any> = [
    {data:{"ID":"123","print":"NO","execTime":"02-16-2020"}},
    {data:{"ID":"124","print":"NO","execTime":"02-14-2020"}},
    {data:{"ID":"125","print":"YES","execTime":"01-16-2020"}},
    {data:{"ID":"126","print":"YES","execTime":"12-11-2019"}}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that, the only way I believe make all the fields as nullable in Data model.
And one level of tree you can make it by using "name" field as treeTableToggler.

```
export interface Data {
  name?: string;
  status?: string;
  AppId?: string;
  GenId?: string;
  ID?: string;
  print?: string;
  execTime?: string;
}

export interface TreeNodeModel {
  data: Data;
  children: Array<TreeNodeModel>;
}
```